# tsconfig.json hell - everything conflicting

Tags: typescript, vite

(node:206511) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/home/benz/Desktop/vite/test/scripts/dev-server.ts:1
import electronPath from 'electron';

then if i add "type": "module" it complains about `Referenced project '/home/benz/Desktop/vite/test/tsconfig.json' must have setting "composite": true.ts`

then I try with "module": "ES6" and then it says Option 'allowImportingTsExtensions' can only be used when either 'noEmit' or 'emitDeclarationOnly' is set

This is nuts I've been on this for 3 hours going cross-eyed!

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ES6",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "composite": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "packages/renderer/vite.config.ts",
    "packages/main/vite.config.ts",
    "packages/preload/vite.config.ts"
  ]
}
```

```
//packages/main/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "types": ["node", "vite/client"]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.d.ts"],
  "references": [
    { "path": "../../tsconfig.json" }
  ]
}
```

I am just trying to follow [this](https://www.jsgarden.co/blog/electron-with-typescript-and-vite-as-a-build-system) to make a main/preload/renderer style vanilla ts starting point. Please someone make it make sense with these tsconfigs. I need to use import in the renderer and require in main and preload both!

Answer (score 1):

```
npm init @quick-start/electron --vanilla
# add name
# choose vanilla
# choose ts
# chose updates
# chose something else (I forget)
# open the folder and
npm install electron-vite --save-dev
npm run dev
```

blam it works!